# iOS How to receive changes of SPM in the app automatically

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I have created Swift package manager, uploaded in Github and I use it in my project, it works fine.
When I make some changes in SPM I must update the package from my project in order to get changes. Is it possible to make updating process automatically so users that already installed the app will get changes when launchs the app?

**Updated**
I worked on project where are swift packages and the role of package was keeping resources (fonts, text styles etc.).
So I would like to know is it possible to provide some info for uses and then change it after while without using API requests?

Second question: If the project is big (2000+ files) can I decrease compilation time by moving some codes to frameworks or swift package? Or framework files compiles every time when we compile the project?

Thanks.

Comment: It’s not possible because the package is part of the (signed) product. What is the benefit without changing any code in the app?

Comment: This isn't possible as you've described it but there are multiple solutions to this problem that exist currently. What's your use case? Do you need to update product features (login, posting, username change etc.)? Do you need to update environmental variables? Do you need to block features that have already been deployed? Tell us more and we can figure out a way to help.

Comment: I worked on project where are swift packages and the role of package was keeping resources (fonts, text styles etc.). So I would like to know is it possible to provide some info for uses and then change it after while without using API requests? 
Second question: If the project is big (2000+ files) can I decrease compilation time by using frameworks or swift package? Or framework files compiles every time when we compile the project? Thanks